# Import multiple contacts under the same account microsoft crm 2013

Tags: crm

I uploaded my contacts and accounts. However some contacts (with duplicate account name) didn't upload. How can I solve this? (I tried duplicate rules and allowed them, but it didn't help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate rules deal with duplicate values within a table.  If you turned on duplicate detection for the account lookup on the contact entity and then imported multiple contacts related to that same account it would yell at you.  The issue here is different; contacts must be related to a single account and the system is finding multiple accounts that could be related based on your rule.  If the process finds more than one potential value for a lookup it will not import the record.

The most straightforward way to get past this issue is to make sure you are setting the account lookup based on a field that is unique.  I assume that currently you are joining with accounts based on the name of the account.  You could either tweak account names in the system so that they are all unique or use something like an account number that you know is unique.  If neither of these options makes sense, and you have some SQL knowledge, you could do the join yourself based on a unique combination of several fields and then update your data source with the primary keys of the accounts).